Where is the error in evaluating this integration? $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2x}}{(1+x^2)^2} dx$
Where is the error in evaluating this integration? $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2x}}{(1+x^2)^2} dx$$
I know $$(-1)^{2x}=1$$
therfore:
$$I=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{(-1)^{2x}}{(1+x^2)^2} dx=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
But using wolfram alpha
$$I = 0.0213... $$

What would you say is $(-1)^{2x}$ when $x=\frac14$?

Yeah, $(-1)^{2x}$ is a problematic expression. It should probably be replaced by $e^{2\pi x i}.$

Your error is assuming that $x$ is an integer. If $x = 1.5$, we have $-1^3 = -1$. $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^2} dx=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ The integral above which you found is correct though :)
